# how to move and recreate sprite in unity2D?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

hey guys im trying to shoot with simple code
i have 2 C# Classes one for Player movements and one for Bullet

this is Bullet Collision Class

```
void Start () {
    source.clip = clip;
    bullet = GetComponent<GameObject>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    bulletPos = player.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D wallCol)
{
    if (wallCol.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
    {
        Debug.Log("Wall Hited!");
        source.Play();
        Destroy(bulletPrefab,clip.length);
        if (bullet == null)
            Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
public void shoot()
{
    rb.velocity = rb.transform.right * bulletSpeed;
}
```

this is Player Movement Class:

```
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && haveGlock == true)
    {
        bc.shoot();
        AudioSource.PlayOneShot(GlockClip);
    }
```

}

i did use shoot   method on another class and when the method called its show me the object reference not set to instance of the object.
also i drag and drop objects in required public variables
 in unity but why its not gonna work?

sorry for my bad English guys.

Comment: Does your bullet have a Rigidbody2D component ? It seems like it's the problem

Comment: yes it does @Jichael

Comment: Why " if (bullet == null)
            Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletPos, Quaternion.identity);" ?? you create an empty game object, its not even put into bullet, bullet is never null..

Comment: Destroy(bulletPrefab,clip.length); - you're trying to destroy a prefab not an instance of it, this also wont work

Comment: thanks.. so have you any soultion? @BugFinder

Comment: So.. right now, your bullets willl move with whatever "bulletPos" is, theres some backwards logic going on. so if it moves 10 units during the lifetime of your bullet, your bullet will move with it.  However, if you only mean to have 1 bullet at a time.. ditch  making the empty gameobject in start, instantiate bullet (bullet = instantiate...)in shoot, and remove its parenting so it moves relative to where it was shot from, then in your trigger should be on the bullet, and it would remove the bullet..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "bc" is assigned in Player Movement Class.

I would do something like that on Player Movement Class.

```
void Update()
   {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && haveGlock == true)
    {
        BulletCollision bc = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletPos, Quaternion.identity);
        bc.shoot();
        AudioSource.PlayOneShot(GlockClip);
    }
```